# how to initialize canvas and react it with vue

Tags: vuejs2

I'm new to Vue.js and I learned some basic skills. Right now I'm trying to solve real problems with it.

I'm trying to draw some donuts with Vue.js. I can make it without Vue easily, but it confuse me while I'm trying to use Vue.js.

```js
/*
  canvas: HTMLCanvas node
  ratio: number range: [0, 1]
*/
function pie (canvas, ratio) {
    function arc (ctx, color, radius, radian) {
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
      ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, radian);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fill();
    }
    
    var width       = canvas.clientWidth, 
        height      = canvas.clientHeight,
        outRadius   = Math.ceil(width / 2 - 10),
        innerRadius = Math.ceil(outRadius * 0.8);
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    
    ctx.save();
    
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    ctx.translate(width / 2, height / 2);
    ctx.rotate(-Math.PI / 2);

    arc(ctx, "steelblue", outRadius, Math.PI * 2);
    arc(ctx, "yellow", outRadius + 5, Math.PI * 2 * ratio);
    arc(ctx, "white", innerRadius, Math.PI * 2);

    ctx.restore();
}

Vue.component("pie", {
    props: ["pies"],
    methods: {
        draw: pie
    },
    template: `
<ul class="pie">
    <li v-for="pie in pies">
       <div class="pie__content">
           <h3 class="pie__header">{{pie.ratio}}</h3>
           <canvas v-on:click="draw($event.target, pie.ratio)" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
       </div>
       <h3 class="pie__name">{{pie.name}}</h3>
    </li>
</ul>
`
});


var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        pies: [
            {ratio: 0.45, name: "CPU"},
            {ratio: 0.75, name: "Memory"},
            {ratio: 0.15, name: "Drive"},
        ]
    }
});
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid gray; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <pie v-bind:pies="pies"></pie>
</div>
```

1. firstly, I don't know how to initialize those canvas. Run those code above you will find those canvas are blank unless user click on them. Absolutely this is not whta I want, but it seems **event** is the only way make it work;
2. secondly, If I change **ratio**, such as: `vm.pies[0].ratio = 0.78`, the 
   related canvas give no response.

Any comments will be appreciated!

Comment: 1) You can invoke the `draw` function in the `mounted` hook. 2) Redraw the canvases in the `updated` hook or use a watcher on the `ratio` value that causes a redraw when the value changes.

Comment: Later I find `mounted` will work according to the [Instance Lifecycle Hooks](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram).  Thanks for your helpful comments!

Answer (score 0):

What I miss is the [Vue Instance Lifecycle](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram). Vue instance offer a `mounted` property which will run after the component is rendered.

1. Firstly, I give the `canvas` element a `ref` attribute which make it easy refered on late manipulation.
2. Creating an `mounted` property function which will run after component is rendered. This could be the initialize function.
3. Creating an `computed` getter function `formatRatio` which will redraw the canvas if availble and finally return the formated `ratio` string in percent format. This part will make the the pie charts reactive with bind data.

Here is the code:

```js
function pie (canvas, ratio) {
    function arc (ctx, color, radius, radian) {
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
      ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, radian);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fill();
    }
    
    var width       = canvas.clientWidth, 
        height      = canvas.clientHeight,
        outRadius   = Math.ceil(width / 2 - 10),
        innerRadius = Math.ceil(outRadius * 0.8);
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    
    ctx.save();
    
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    ctx.translate(width / 2, height / 2);
    ctx.rotate(-Math.PI / 2);

    arc(ctx, "steelblue", outRadius, Math.PI * 2);
    arc(ctx, "yellow", outRadius + 5, Math.PI * 2 * ratio);
    arc(ctx, "white", innerRadius, Math.PI * 2);

    ctx.restore();
}


Vue.component("pie-canvas", {
    props: ["pie"],
    computed: {
        formatRatio: function () {
            // when component is rendered canvas element will be avaible
            if (this.$refs.canvas) {
                pie(this.$refs.canvas, this.pie.ratio);
            }
            return Math.round(this.pie.ratio * 1000) / 10 + "%";
        }
    },
    mounted: function () {
        pie(this.$refs.canvas, this.pie.ratio);
    },
    template: `
<div class="pie__content">
   <h3 class="pie__header">{{ formatRatio }}</h3>
   <canvas ref="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
</div>
`
});

var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        pies: [
            {ratio: 0.45, name: "CPU"},
            {ratio: 0.75, name: "Memory"},
            {ratio: 0.15, name: "Drive"},
        ]
    }
});
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid gray; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<ul class="pie">
    <li v-for="pie in pies">
       <pie-canvas v-bind:pie="pie"></pie-canvas>
       <h3 class="pie__name">{{pie.name}}</h3>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```